# A Question on Commas

Tags: grammar, commas, time

I've noticed that in all sentences I come across which start with an indication of time, there is always a comma after before the sentence is continued.
For example:
When I was five, I bought my first bike.
In 1910, John Smith was born.
Over the years, I grew to hate celery.

Why is this? Why must there be a comma when, saying the sentences out loud, there is no indication of a pause?

Comment: When I say these sentences aloud, I do pause.

Comment: @James Webster I do as well, a comma seems appropriate to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are starting the sentence with an [introduction](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/commas_after_a_sentence_introduction.htm).  An indication of time is only one form of introduction.

> At 4 o'clock, I'll jump in the river.
>
> As I know the ground, I'll go first.
>
> Under the water, you can see the swans' legs going hell for leather.

The fancy term for them adverbial clauses or phrases.